# apt-get update in postint of a deb package

Tags: packaging, deb

I want to launch a apt-get update in postint of a deb file, I create deb to add repository to my distro, but the apt show an error that there are another process apt, the installation. Any idea?¿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds familiar; I don't think it's possible to run apt-get in maintainer scripts. The deb file for Google Chrome includes code for adding their repository, but AFAICR it's somewhat complicated. You may want to take a look, though.

Comment: Chrome's deb file doesn't run apt-get update. It just adds a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` subject to a variable set in `/etc/default/google-chrome`.

Comment: Right, @muru, it doesn't run `apt-get update` because it can't. But the postinst script includes code for preparing e.g. the files you mention, and it also includes code for adding the signing key, which is a nifty detail.